# Manage related project deployment in Continuous Deployment

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, continuous-deployment

I am planning of using Visual Studio TFS server for Continuous Deployment.

I have few projects which are related and when a particular project is updated it might rigger a change in that related project

E.g. Web Project and a Middle Layer API project

Now when I follow CD , how can I ensure that Middle layer API project is deployed before the Web Project is deployed

Comment: You define the release process using environments, and define the automation in each environment using phases and [tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/tasks?view=vsts). A task is simply a packaged script or procedure that has been abstracted with a set of inputs. The release process is flexible with tasks. You could add tasks that you need to deploy the Middle layer API project first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create only one release to deploy your two related projects.
Choose one of them as the main artifact. Let's say the web project.

At the artifacts page in the release configuration, add your middle layer project as another artifact to the release.

Now that you have your two target projects, setup your release pipeline so that you add the steps to deploy your layer project before your web project.

Comment: This is effectively deploy all the  applications, which might not be necessary,